# Limiting Spry Tabbed Panels Effect on Menu

Tags: panels, spry, tabbed

i am creating a drop down menu with the Spry Tabbed Panels widget. I am trying to find a way to have the roll-over/drop-down effect only work on a couple of the tabs. (I have about 10 tabs in all.) The remainder of the tabs, I would just like to use as normal links without drop-downs, but maintain the styling as if they are still part of the Spry widget. Is there some code I can take out or something so that I could accomplish this? Here is the code I have right now:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanelsHeader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanelsHeader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Pregnancy</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="1">Pregnancy Week by Week</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Newborn Baby</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Women's Health</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Nutrition &amp; Beauty</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Menopause</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Teen Health</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Mom's Blog &amp; Forums</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Videos</li>
</ul>
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Pregnancy Topics | Pregnancy Explained A-Z | Pregnancy Videos</div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Pregnancy Weeks Guide | First Trimester {Weeks 1-13} | Second Trimester {Weeks 14-28} | Third Trimester {Weeks 29-40}</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
//-->
</script>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
    // SpryTabbedPanels.js - version 0.6 - Spry Pre-Release 1.6.1
//
// Copyright (c) 2006. Adobe Systems Incorporated.
// All rights reserved.
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
//
//   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
//     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
//     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
//     and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
//   * Neither the name of Adobe Systems Incorporated nor the names of its
//     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this
//     software without specific prior written permission.
//
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
// AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
// IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
// ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
// CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
// SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
// INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
// CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
// ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
// POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

var Spry;
if (!Spry) Spry = {};
if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels = function(element, opts)
{
    this.element = this.getElement(element);
    this.defaultTab = 0; // Show the first panel by default.
    this.tabSelectedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
    this.tabHoverClass = "TabbedPanelsTabHover";
    this.tabFocusedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabFocused";
    this.panelVisibleClass = "TabbedPanelsContentVisible";
    this.focusElement = null;
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.currentTabIndex = 0;
    this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
    this.nextPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT;
    this.previousPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT;

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions(this, opts);

    // If the defaultTab is expressed as a number/index, convert
    // it to an element.

    if (typeof (this.defaultTab) == "number")
    {
        if (this.defaultTab < 0)
            this.defaultTab = 0;
        else
        {
            var count = this.getTabbedPanelCount();
            if (this.defaultTab >= count)
                this.defaultTab = (count > 1) ? (count - 1) : 0;
        }

        this.defaultTab = this.getTabs()[this.defaultTab];
    }

    // The defaultTab property is supposed to be the tab element for the tab content
    // to show by default. The caller is allowed to pass in the element itself or the
    // element's id, so we need to convert the current value to an element if necessary.

    if (this.defaultTab)
        this.defaultTab = this.getElement(this.defaultTab);

    this.attachBehaviors();
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
    if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
        return document.getElementById(ele);
    return ele;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElementChildren = function(element)
{
    var children = [];
    var child = element.firstChild;
    while (child)
    {
        if (child.nodeType == 1 /* Node.ELEMENT_NODE */)
            children.push(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return children;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.addClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) != -1))
        return;
    ele.className += (ele.className ? " " : "") + className;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.removeClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1))
        return;
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + className + "\\b", "g"), "");
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions = function(obj, optionsObj, ignoreUndefinedProps)
{
    if (!optionsObj)
        return;
    for (var optionName in optionsObj)
    {
        if (ignoreUndefinedProps && optionsObj[optionName] == undefined)
            continue;
        obj[optionName] = optionsObj[optionName];
    }
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabGroup = function()
{
    if (this.element)
    {
        var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
        if (children.length)
            return children[0];
    }
    return null;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabs = function()
{
    var tabs = [];
    var tg = this.getTabGroup();
    if (tg)
        tabs = this.getElementChildren(tg);
    return tabs;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanelGroup = function()
{
    if (this.element)
    {
        var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
        if (children.length > 1)
            return children[1];
    }
    return null;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanels = function()
{
    var panels = [];
    var pg = this.getContentPanelGroup();
    if (pg)
        panels = this.getElementChildren(pg);
    return panels;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getIndex = function(ele, arr)
{
    ele = this.getElement(ele);
    if (ele && arr && arr.length)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (ele == arr[i])
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabIndex = function(ele)
{
    var i = this.getIndex(ele, this.getTabs());
    if (i < 0)
        i = this.getIndex(ele, this.getContentPanels());
    return i;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getCurrentTabIndex = function()
{
    return this.currentTabIndex;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabbedPanelCount = function(ele)
{
    return Math.min(this.getTabs().length, this.getContentPanels().length);
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener = function(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
    try
    {
        if (element.addEventListener)
            element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
        else if (element.attachEvent)
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
    }
    catch (e) {}
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.cancelEvent = function(e)
{
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    else e.returnValue = false;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;

    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabClick = function(e, tab)
{
    this.showPanel(tab);
    return this.cancelEvent(e);
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabMouseOver = function(e, tab)
{
    this.addClassName(tab, this.tabHoverClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabMouseOut = function(e, tab)
{
    this.removeClassName(tab, this.tabHoverClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabFocus = function(e, tab)
{
    this.hasFocus = true;
    this.addClassName(tab, this.tabFocusedClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabBlur = function(e, tab)
{
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.removeClassName(tab, this.tabFocusedClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_UP = 38;
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_DOWN = 40;
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT = 37;
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT = 39;



Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabKeyDown = function(e, tab)
{
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!this.hasFocus || (key != this.previousPanelKeyCode && key != this.nextPanelKeyCode))
        return true;

    var tabs = this.getTabs();
    for (var i =0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        if (tabs[i] == tab)
        {
            var el = false;
            if (key == this.previousPanelKeyCode && i > 0)
                el = tabs[i-1];
            else if (key == this.nextPanelKeyCode && i < tabs.length-1)
                el = tabs[i+1];

            if (el)
            {
                this.showPanel(el);
                el.focus();
                break;
            }
        }

    return this.cancelEvent(e);
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.preorderTraversal = function(root, func)
{
    var stopTraversal = false;
    if (root)
    {
        stopTraversal = func(root);
        if (root.hasChildNodes())
        {
            var child = root.firstChild;
            while (!stopTraversal && child)
            {
                stopTraversal = this.preorderTraversal(child, func);
                try { child = child.nextSibling; } catch (e) { child = null; }
            }
        }
    }
    return stopTraversal;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.addPanelEventListeners = function(tab, panel)
{
    var self = this;
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseover", function(e) { return self.onTabClick(e, tab); }, false);
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseover", function(e) { return self.onTabMouseOver(e, tab); }, false);
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseout", function(e) { return self.onTabMouseOut(e, tab); }, false);

    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
    {
        // XXX: IE doesn't allow the setting of tabindex dynamically. This means we can't
        // rely on adding the tabindex attribute if it is missing to enable keyboard navigation
        // by default.

        // Find the first element within the tab container that has a tabindex or the first
        // anchor tag.

        var tabIndexEle = null;
        var tabAnchorEle = null;

        this.preorderTraversal(tab, function(node) {
            if (node.nodeType == 1 /* NODE.ELEMENT_NODE */)
            {
                var tabIndexAttr = tab.attributes.getNamedItem("tabindex");
                if (tabIndexAttr)
                {
                    tabIndexEle = node;
                    return true;
                }
                if (!tabAnchorEle && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a")
                    tabAnchorEle = node;
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (tabIndexEle)
            this.focusElement = tabIndexEle;
        else if (tabAnchorEle)
            this.focusElement = tabAnchorEle;

        if (this.focusElement)
        {
            Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "focus", function(e) { return self.onTabFocus(e, tab); }, false);
            Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "blur", function(e) { return self.onTabBlur(e, tab); }, false);
            Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "keydown", function(e) { return self.onTabKeyDown(e, tab); }, false);
        }
    }
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.showPanel = function(elementOrIndex)
{
    var tpIndex = -1;

    if (typeof elementOrIndex == "number")
        tpIndex = elementOrIndex;
    else // Must be the element for the tab or content panel.
        tpIndex = this.getTabIndex(elementOrIndex);

    if (!tpIndex < 0 || tpIndex >= this.getTabbedPanelCount())
        return;

    var tabs = this.getTabs();
    var panels = this.getContentPanels();

    var numTabbedPanels = Math.max(tabs.length, panels.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < numTabbedPanels; i++)
    {
        if (i != tpIndex)
        {
            if (tabs[i])
                this.removeClassName(tabs[i], this.tabSelectedClass);
            if (panels[i])
            {
                this.removeClassName(panels[i], this.panelVisibleClass);
                panels[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    this.addClassName(tabs[tpIndex], this.tabSelectedClass);
    this.addClassName(panels[tpIndex], this.panelVisibleClass);
    panels[tpIndex].style.display = "block";

    this.currentTabIndex = tpIndex;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.attachBehaviors = function(element)
{
    var tabs = this.getTabs();
    var panels = this.getContentPanels();
    var panelCount = this.getTabbedPanelCount();

    for (var i = 0; i < panelCount; i++)
        this.addPanelEventListeners(tabs[i], panels[i]);

    this.showPanel(this.defaultTab);
};
```

As you will see, I only want the drop-down affect on "Pregnancy" and "Pregnancy Week by Week". When you mouseover "Newborn Baby", a line of javascript comes up that I don't want to be there. Any way to make this go away? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Thank you BurnAfterReading :-)

Comment: I actually figured it out myself, but stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question until 8 hours after I post it. lol It was actually a Css fix and not a part of the javascript at all. I just had to move around a couple Css names and it works now :-) thanks anyway!